# Cómo agregar links en archivo locales de traducción?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, enlace, i18n, yml

Estoy usando `simple_form` y tengo un campo que es una colección de payment_types

```
<%= p.input :accepted_payment_types,
            as: :check_boxes,
            collection: all_payment_options_for_form, # helper que devuelve un array de opciones
            wrapper: :vertical_collection,
            %>
```

helper:

```
  def all_payment_options_for_form
    AccountPreferencesSet::SELECTOR_PAYMENT_TYPES.map do |payment_type|
      [sanitize(t("payment_types.#{payment_type}"), tags: %w(a)), payment_type]
    end
  end
```

Estamos usando `locales` para mostrar los nombres de las opciones y su descripción

```
payment_types:
    credit_card: "Débito Automático con Tarjeta"
    cbu: "Débito Automático con CBU.
    prepaid: "Prepago"
```

La cuestión es que para una de esas opciones (cbu) necesito ofrecer un link a un recurso externo.

Probé lo siguiente:

```
payment_types:
    credit_card: "Débito Automático con Tarjeta"
    cbu: "Débito Automático con CBU. Requiere habilitación previa de su Banco. <a href="www.google.com">Ver tutorial</a> "
    prepaid: "Prepago"
```

Pero me crashea Rails indicandome que no puede cargar las traducciones para la página (tal vez porque no estoy escapando los "" en la URL y se rompe el locales.yml).

Sé que tiene que ver con la URL que estoy agregando a ese key, porque el error al que hace referencia Rails es al traducir la navbar de la página que en el `locales` está más abajo que la traducción con la URL que estoy agregando (es decir, es como si se rompiera en el key que tiene la URL y no llegara a la traducción de la navbar que está más abajo en el `locales.yml`).

Cual sería la manera de implementarlo o la corrección?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Efectivamente el problema estaba en las " " de la traducción, puesto que el mismo  tag contiene "" también.

Quitarle los "" de más al principio de la traducción funcionó:

```
cbu: Débito Automático con CBU. Requiere habilitación previa de su Banco. <a href="www.google.com">Ver tutorial</a>
```

Comment: Otra opción es "escapar" las comillas con backslashes: `link: "<a href=\"www.google.com\">"`.

Answer (score 0):

Hay varias formas que puedes usar. Como mencionas, efectivamente puedes omitir las comillas que rodean a la traducción:

```
cbu: Débito Automático con CBU. Requiere habilitación previa de su Banco. <a href="www.google.com">Ver tutorial</a>
```

el problema con esta forma es que si usas algún carácter especial para el formato YAML, como `:`, vas a tener problemas.

Lo otro es rodear con comillas simples que no conflictúen con las comillas dobles:

```
cbu: 'Débito Automático con CBU. Requiere habilitación previa de su Banco. <a href="www.google.com">Ver tutorial</a>'
```

Pero sucede algo similar al paso anterior, ya que si usas una comilla simple en alguna parte dentro de la traducción, fallará.

La tercera opción, como mencionan en comentarios, es escapando las comillas con backslash `\`:

```
cbu:"Débito Automático con CBU. Requiere habilitación previa de su Banco. <a href=\"www.google.com\">Ver tutorial</a>"
```

Que claro, es un problema tener que estar agregando `\` por doquier.

Por tanto existe una última opción, que personalmente es la que usaría, que es usar texto multilínea con `|`

```
cbu: | 
  Débito Automático con CBU. Requiere habilitación previa de su Banco. 
  <a href="www.google.com">Ver tutorial</a>
```

donde no necesitas escapar nada ni rodear el texto con caracteres extras, aparte que queda mucho más legible en vez de una línea de texto interminable.

Un detalle extra, al renderizar la traducción con `<%= t('cbu') %>` de seguro te escapará todos los tags que tengas definido, para evitar esto, puedes definir el key de tu traducción con el sufijo `_html`:

```
cbu_html: | 
  Débito Automático con CBU. Requiere habilitación previa de su Banco. 
  <a href="www.google.com">Ver tutorial</a>
```

Y luego al llamar a `<%= t('cbu_html') %>`, rails renderizará los tags html sin problemas.